# BSOD on a laptop under Windows 7 pro

Tags: bsod

I'm having every 15/20mn a BSOD with "driver_power_state_failure" in my windows 7 professional on my Dell Vostro 3750... I didn't installed any material even made an update for several weeks... I don't know how to manage this problem. Should you help please?

Pict: [image]

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. It is probably better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Disconnect your hard disk, and the put it back properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably overheating or hard disk failure. Did you clean the laptop.

Comment: Sounds more like a driver problem to me.

Comment: He didn't change anything since weeks.

Comment: It seems it is heating, yes... I've put an object under the laptop to make the air pass through and it seems to be ok, no BSOD for more than 2 hours... I've ordered a notebook cooler... We'll see if it ok with that... Thanks